# Stack Exchange very slow

Tags: support, stack-exchange

It seems that Stack Exchange is running very slow. Especially on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), where I am having trouble reading questions and posting answers.

Are there any issues? [Stack Status](http://stackstatus.net/) doens't report anything.

Comment: Yeap, got the same problem here.

Comment: I'll take that back, http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/stackoverflow.com.html also reports issues.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I Don't think. I can open other US websites without issues

Comment: It is going much better now

Answer (score 36):

Yes, we are having some issues.

These are currently being investigated and we hope to get a fix out soonish.

In the meantime, I will be looking for who plugged in something into itself and deal with both.

---

We were hit by a botnet causing the slowdowns seen earlier.

Once a full post-mortem of the event has been finished, it will be posted on http://stackstatus.net

Comment: that is the price to build everything on your own instead of using the cloud. /joke

Comment: @dynamic - yeah, with the cloud, when things go bang and it isn't your code, you are stuffed ;)

Comment: It's better already. Guess that self-plugged thing and its commiter both ran away in panic after reading your post.

Comment: I noticed that the top meta questions section isn't appearing. Could be one place to look.   Funny, looks like everything is back to normal now on my end.

Comment: @Oded FYI might not be related but now every few minutes or so I receive notifications on my Stack Exchange mobile app about comments directed to me for the past 2 days (so far)

Comment: Should be OK - RJ45's don't take fingerprints well.

Comment: *botnet* - looks like script kiddies decided to take revenge for the deletion of their "give me teh codez" questions.

Comment: Ahh!!! Thanks. I was thinking, am the only person hitting this entire day.

Comment: @AndréDaniel a true give-me-the-codez kid would have asked "How can I hack Stack Overflow" on SO...